# Issue extracting month and year from datetime column

Tags: pandas

I have column in my pandas df like this

```
0      2020-03-26 00:00:00-10:00
1      2020-03-26 00:30:00-10:00
2      2020-03-26 01:00:00-10:00
3      2020-03-26 01:30:00-10:00
4      2020-03-26 02:00:00-10:00
```

(Actual df is much larger)
I am trying to extract year and month out of this.
I am doing this: `df['t'].apply(lambda a: (a.year, a.month)`

this is throwing error : `ValueError: MultiIndex has no single backing array. Use 'MultiIndex.to_numpy()' to get a NumPy array of tuples.`

How to solve

Comment: IIUC, `df['t'].dt.strftime("%Y-%M")`? Link to [`pd.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for more info.

Comment: Here it looks like your dataframe has `t` as index that's why the error. I tried your code where `df["t"]` is type `datetime64[ns]` and it works. Off course  @Ch3steR solution here is the fastest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'t': ['2020-03-26 00:00:00-10:00', '2020-03-26 00:30:00-10:00', '2020-03-26 01:00:00-10:00', '2020-03-26 01:30:00-10:00', '2020-03-26 02:00:00-10:00']}) 

df['t'].apply(lambda a: (pd.to_datetime(a).strftime('%Y-%B')))
```